# How do I reset "Edit Web Part" - Unable to re-add webpart?

Tags: web-part, content-editor-web-part, edit-form, editing-menu, edit

When I click edit on an item in a list, I get a blank page.

I'm investigating this and discovered that when I go to "Form Web Parts - Default Edit Form" that there are no web parts on that page.

I've attempted to add various web parts to that page, but can't figure out how to re-add the correct webpart in "edit mode"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this.  Basically I created a new form, and edited the name, list id GUID, and the name GUID as described below.

http://itsolutionsblog.net/content/uploads/copy-form-and-edit.png